# Insert an element to Array List sorted descending order

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I'm trying to insert an element in the correct position in an array list that is sorted in descending order.
The complexity to find the correct position must be O(LOGN).
That's why I tried using binary search to find the correct position.
This is what I did:

I added:

**middle = (low + high) / 2;**

after the while loop.

The problem is that it's inserting the elements in ascending order. instead of descending order

```
public void insert(E x) {

    if(q.size()==0){
        q.add(0, x);
    }
    else{
        int place = binarySearch(x);
        q.add(place, x);
    }
}

private int binarySearch (E x) {
    int size = q.size();
    int low = 0;
    int high = size - 1;
    int middle = 0;

    while(high > low) {
        middle = (low + high) / 2;
        if(q.get(middle).getPriority() == x.getPriority()) {
            return middle;
        }
        if(q.get(middle).getPriority() < x.getPriority()) {
            low = middle + 1;
        }
        if(q.get(middle).getPriority() > x.getPriority()) {
            high = middle - 1;
        }
    }
```

**middle = (low + high) / 2;**

```
    if(q.get(middle).getPriority() < x.getPriority()) {
        return middle + 1 ;
    }
    return middle;

}
```

Comment: I mean that the complexity to find the correct position must be O(LOGN).I edit the post.

Comment: Check the answer again. I edited it.

Comment: Can you expand on *it's not working correctly*.

Comment: @notyou If I add this: middle = (low + high) / 2;  after the while loop, it's inserting the elements in ascending order. instead of descending order

Comment: "It's not working" is not a problem description. Debug your code and try to localize the error.

Comment: note that when using array list, the worst case complexity would be O(N) - when you have to add a new member to the 1st cell, so you have to move each object in the cell one object down (or just create a new array and move the objects).

Comment: If it sorts in ascending order, you should probably just swap all the `>` and `<`

Comment: @vanje I edited the post. The problem is that it's inserting the elements in ascending order. instead of descending order.

Comment: @tobias_k swapping all the > and < is not good enough

Comment: @sara No, there must be some other off-by-one error, but it's probably a good start, and certainly necessary.

Comment: Use `Collections.binarySearch`. It will give you the solution much faster.

Comment: @AxelH  does it works in descending order?

Comment: You can give the method a comparator : [binarySearch(List<? extends T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> c](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

- all your comparisons are the wrong way, thus you are inserting in ascending order
- you should loop `while (high >= low)`, or you can not insert an element that's smaller than all the existing elements; also, with this you no longer need the `if/else` in `insert`
- if you want ties to be handled such that the oldest element is sorted first, remove the "same as middle" check and reverse the `if/else` within the loop; this way, in case of ties, the `low` bound is raised, inserting the new element after the older one
- now, after the `while` loop, you can just return `low`

This seems to work (Note: Changed to `Integer` instead of `E` for testing, populating an initially empty list with random integers.):

```
public void insert(E x) {
    q.add(binarySearch(x), x);
}

private int binarySearch (E x) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = q.size() - 1;
    while (high >= low) {
        int middle = (low + high) / 2;
        if (q.get(middle).getPriority() < x.getPriority()) {
            high = middle - 1;
        } else {
            low = middle + 1;
        }
    }
    return low;
}
```

Tests and example output:

```
@Data @AllArgsConstructor
class E {
    int id, priority;
    public String toString() { return String.format("%d/%d", id, priority); }
}

Random random = new Random();
int id = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    test.insert(new E(id++, random.nextInt(20)));
}
System.out.println(test.q);
// [2/19, 3/19, 24/19, 32/19, 46/19, 18/18, 23/18, 39/18, 31/17, 10/16, 28/16, 40/16, 45/16, 7/15, 19/14, 33/14, 37/14, 38/14, 36/13, 44/13, 5/11, 12/11, 15/11, 20/11, 30/11, 9/10, 41/10, 48/10, 16/9, 34/9, 13/8, 1/7, 8/7, 35/7, 0/6, 6/6, 22/6, 29/6, 21/5, 26/5, 42/5, 14/4, 27/4, 47/4, 25/3, 4/1, 11/1, 17/1, 43/1, 49/0]
```

Comment: How could I change it that the element that is inserted first will be first between elements with the same value?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a lot simpler using [`Collections.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29). The methods will return the index if it is found or return a negative value matching where it should be :

> the index of the search key, if it is contained in the list; otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1). The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the list: the index of the first element greater than the key, or list.size() if all elements in the list are less than the specified key. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.

Here is a quick example of a `SortedList`

```
class SortedList<E> extends ArrayList<E>{

    Comparator<E> comparator;

    public SortedList(Comparator<E> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        int index = Collections.binarySearch(this, e, comparator);

        if(index < 0){
            index = -index - 1;
        }
        if(index >= this.size()){
            super.add(e);
        } else {
            super.add(index, e);
        } 
        return true;
    }
}
```

And a test case for a descending order:

```
SortedList<Integer> list = new SortedList<>(
             (i1,  i2) -> i2 - i1
        );
list.add(10);
list.add(20);
list.add(15);
list.add(10);

System.out.println(list);
```

> [20, 15, 10, 10]

The `comparator` in the constructor allow you to set the order to use for the insertion. Not that this is not safe, this is not overriding every methods but this is a quick answer ;)